# Template Engine refactoring

Tags: php, templates

```
   $global_models =
            array(12) {
              ["page.login"]=>
              string(1) "2"
              ["page.item.id"]=>
              string(3) "new"
              ["page.content.title"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["page.trigger.date"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["page.trigger.url"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["page.trigger.admin_only"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["page.content.body"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["page..ga"]=>
              string(27) "GA1.2.1694644634.1491872034"
              ["prompt.message"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["prompt.error"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["page.tags"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["name"]=>
                array(2) {
                  [0]=>
                  string(2) "xx"
                  [1]=>
                  string(2) "yy"
                }
              }
              ["page.custom"]=>
              array(2) {
                ["header"]=>
                array(2) {
                  [0]=>
                  string(0) "1"
                  [1]=>
                  string(1) "a"
                }
                ["value"]=>
                array(2) {
                  [0]=>
                  string(0) "2"
                  [1]=>
                  string(1) "b"
                }
              }
            }
```

Code:

```
        foreach ($global_models as $var => $data) {
            // when model data is an array
            if (is_array($data)) {
                // fetch for blocks and render loops
                $forblocks = array();
                preg_match_all('/(?<block>\[for:'.$var.'\](?<content>[\s\S]+)\[end:'.$var.'\])/ix', $view_output, $forblocks, PREG_SET_ORDER);
                if (count($forblocks)) {
                    foreach ($forblocks as $foundForBlock) {
                        $foreach_data = '';
                        foreach ($data as $mykey => $row) {
                            // set model values within the loop, ex: blocks.x value
                            $block_content = $foundForBlock['content'];
                            foreach ($row as $subvar => $value) {
                                if (!is_array($value)) {
                                    $block_content = str_replace('['.$var.'.'.$subvar.']', $value, $block_content);
                                    //$block_content = str_replace('['.$var.'.'.$mykey.']', $value, $block_content);
                                }
                            }
                            // append the parsed new block (of for loop) as processed view to render (ifs and setters for example)
                            $foreach_data .=  $this->process_view($controller, $block_content, $recursion_level + 1);
                        }
                        $view_output = str_replace($foundForBlock['block'], $foreach_data, $view_output);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // simple model, replace model with value ex: "[stats.x]" by "18"
                $view_output = str_replace('['.$var.']', $data, $view_output);
            }
        }
```

Issue:

Key to value pair works

my blocks of data don't work...

```
$viewoutput =
"
    [page.login]
"
```

should result in

```
"
2
"
```

This:

```
$viewoutput =
"
[for:page.custom]
      [page.custom.header] - [page.custom.value]
[end:page.custom]
"
```

should result in

```
"
    1 - 2
    a - b
"
```

This:

```
$viewoutput =

"
[for:page.tags]
      [page.tags.name]
[end:page.tags]
"
```

should result in

```
"
    xx
    yy
"
```

I've refactored my code about 20 times and each time I get a headache...!

Someone please help?

Thanks and viva la community! :)

Comment: Full code available here:
https://github.com/LucLaverdure/ShiftSmith/blob/master/core/core-process.php

Comment: Can you tell me what you are trying to do with your `$global_models` so that we can help you out.

Comment: Parse view_output with values from $global_models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed myself...

```
        // process shared models (variables)
        foreach ($global_models as $var => $data) {
            // when model data is an array
            if (is_array($data)) {
                // fetch for blocks and render loops
                $forblocks = array();
                preg_match_all('/(?<block>\[for:'.$var.'\](?<content>[\s\S]+)\[end:'.$var.'\])/ix', $view_output, $forblocks, PREG_SET_ORDER);
                if (count($forblocks)) {
                    foreach ($forblocks as $foundForBlock) {
                        $block_content = array();
                        foreach ($data as $mykey => $row) {
                        //$foreach_data = '';
                            // set model values within the loop, ex: blocks.x value
                            foreach ($row as $subvar => $value) {
                                if (!isset($block_content[$subvar])) $block_content[$subvar] = $foundForBlock['content'];
                                if (!is_array($value)) {
                                    if (is_numeric($subvar)) {
                                        $block_content[$subvar] = str_replace('['.$var.'.'.$mykey.']', $value, $block_content[$subvar]);

                                    } 
                                }
                            }
                            // append the parsed new block (of for loop) as processed view to render (ifs and setters for example)
                        }
                        $block_content = implode("\n", $block_content);
                        $view_output = str_replace($foundForBlock['block'], $block_content, $view_output);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // simple model, replace model with value ex: "[stats.x]" by "18"
                $view_output = str_replace('['.$var.']', $data, $view_output);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried my self best to get it done. I know this is not a generic solution but it will solve your current problem. You must use different function for using `loop`(`[for:page.custom]`) and `simple`(`[page.login]`) attribute. I have already went through this issue. I also solved one of my problem by this, Here you should define seperate function which will first decide which function will handle modification whether it is for loop or for simple. But for now i have fixed your issue with a single php function.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/777053)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$global_models = array(
    "page.login" => "2",
    "page.item.id" => "new",
    "page.content.title" => "",
    "page.trigger.date" => "",
    "page.trigger.url" => "",
    "page.trigger.admin_only" => "N",
    "page.content.body" => "testing",
    "page..ga" => "GA1.2.1694644634.1491872034",
    "prompt.message" => "",
    "prompt.error" => "",
    "page.tags" =>
    array(
        "name" =>
        array(
            0 => "xx",
            1 => "yy"
        )
    ),
    "page.custom" =>
    array(
        "header" =>
        array(
            0 => "1",
            1 => "a",
        ),
        "value" =>
        array(
            0 => "2",
            1 => "b",
        )
    )
);
$viewoutput =
"
    [page.content.body]
[for:page.custom]
      [page.custom.header] - [page.custom.value]
[end:page.custom]
";

echo modify($viewoutput);

function modify($viewoutput)
{
    $returnString="";
    global $global_models;
    $segments=explode("\n", $viewoutput);
    $counter=0;
    while(count($segments)>0)
    {
        $segment=$segments[$counter];
        if (preg_match("/\[for:\K([\w\.]+)\]/", $segment,$matches))
        {
            unset($segments[$counter]);
            $counter++;
            $segment=$segments[$counter];
            $pointer=0;
            $data=array();

            preg_match_all("/\.([\w]+)\]/", $segment,$segmentMatches);
            for($x=0;$x<count($global_models[$matches[1]][$segmentMatches[1][0]]);$x++)
            {
                $newString=$segment;
                foreach($segmentMatches[1] as $toReplace)
                {
                    $newString=  str_replace("[".$matches[1].".".$toReplace."]", $global_models[$matches[1]][$toReplace][$x], $newString);
                }
                $data[]=$newString;
            }
        }
        elseif(preg_match("/\[end:\K([\w\.]+)\]/", $segment))
        {
            $returnString.=  implode("\n", $data);
        }
        elseif(preg_match("/\[([\w\.]+)\]/", $segment,$matches1) && !preg_match("/\[for:\K([\w\.]+)\]/", $segment,$matches))
        {
            $returnString=$returnString.$global_models[$matches1[1]]."\n";
        }
        else
        {
            $returnString=$returnString.$segment."\n";
        }
        unset($segments[$counter]);
        $counter++;
    }
    return $returnString;
}
```

Comment: I will revise this soon, issue remains open for best answer, cheers!

Comment: @LucLaverdure Can i ask you what would be the best answer for you?

Comment: This can only analyze code by lines, I may use this and alter it. But it's way too late here to commit code :)

Comment: @LucLaverdure I have updated my post with a complex example. You can check it, if you like it you can accept this. Here single function will do the thing which you require.

Comment: Doesn`t work if everything is on the same line:

$viewoutput =
"
    [page.content.body] [for:page.custom]       [page.custom.header] - [page.custom.value] [end:page.custom]
";

Comment: doesn't work either if there is simple tags within loop